# HTML Escapes

Tags: url-encoding

Given:

```
CR = %0d = \r
LF = %0a = \n
```

What does

%3E,
%3C

Mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are URL encoded characters.  %3C is <, %3E is >

More info on [URL Encoding](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm), and [a chart](http://www.asciitable.com/) of some of the lower ASCII values.

Answer (score 6):

paste

```
javascript:alert(unescape("%3E"))
```

into a browser's address bar and hit Return to find out ;)

Comment: Thank you, this will help if I have any other questions.

Answer (score 2):

The two digits after the % is an [ASCII](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) code represented in [hexadecimal](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).